# Bypass/skip table rows that contains cell with no text using selenium and xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm sure that this question has a simple answer, but after hours of research and testing, I haven't resolved the problem.

Here is the issue.  I recently started using selenium to harvest information from a website that creates dynamic tables. During testing I noted that I was have some issues when I was reviewing the data collected.  After some data review I noticed that some of the table fields were missing text, which created errors that showed up in a second section of the code.  I have decided to bypass these table entries within my code, but I still get errors, so my code is incorrect.

```
# I'm obtaining the <td> tags in the table
# with this.
td = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td")

# I slice out the desired items this way
# This outputs a <class 'str'>
td[3].text

# I found that this item has no text in some 
# table rows, which causes issues. I have tried 
# using the following to catch and bypass these
# rows

if not td[3].text:
   pass
else:
  # run some code
  # harvest the entire row


if len(td[3].text) != 0:
  # run some code
  # harvest the entire row
else:
  pass 


if len(td[3].text) == 11:
  # run some code
  # harvest the entire row
else:
  pass 


if td[3].text) != '':
  # run some code
  # harvest the entire row
else:
  pass 

# this element is the one that might be empty
td_time = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[4]/span/time")
if (len(td_time.text)) != 11:
   print ('no')
elif (len(td_time.text)) == 11:
   print ('yes')
```

The table that I'm scraping has five columns.  The last column contains dates, which are missing in some rows that contained older data.

```
# Example with date
<td headers="th-date th-4206951" class="td-date">
   <b class="cell-label ng-binding">Publish Date</b>
   <span class="cell-content"><time datetime="2019-06-05T00:00:00Z" class="ng-binding">04 Jun 2019</time></span>
</td>

# Example without date
<td headers="th-date th-2037023" class="td-date">
  <b class="cell-label ng-binding">Publish Date</b>
  <span class="cell-content"><time datetime="" class="ng-binding"></time></span>
</td>
```

None of these code examples catch the empty text blocks, which causes issue when post-processing the collected data.

So my question is: How do I bypass an element obtained using XPATH that has no text?

Comment: Try `".//td/*[text()]"`

Comment: are you suggesting this: td = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td/*[text()]")

Comment: Yes, based on my limited knowledge of xpath, that might work.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work.   I will do some research based on your suggestion.

Comment: Can you post at least a part of the table with some `td[3]` with and without text?

Comment: @JackFleeting I have added this info.

Comment: Just to clarify again - the only difference I can see between your two `<td>`s is that in the 2nd, the `datetime` attribute of the `<time>` child tag has no value, while in the 1st it has the value `2019-06-05T00:00:00Z`. So you want to skip the 2nd `<td>` in its entirety. Is all this correct?

Comment: if the child tag has no value then I want to skip harvesting the entire row.

Comment: Well, I can't get it done with selenium, but it can be easily done with lxml. Let me know if you're interested and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply check for the below element.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts-with(@id,'mytable')]/tbody/tr[not(td[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=0])]")
for r in rows:
    columns = r.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for col in columns:
        print (col.text)
```

Sample HTML:

```html
<html><head></head><body><table border="1" id="mytable">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>FR</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>SR</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>TR</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td> </td>
  <td>Checking cell with only space</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>All</td>
  <td>Rows</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

Here is the JQuery to get all rows that doesn't have empty cells.

```
var list_of_cells =[];
$x("//table[starts-with(@id,'mytable')]/tbody/tr[not(td[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=0])]").forEach(function(row){
 var colData= [];
 row.childNodes.forEach(function(col){
 if(col.nodeType!=3){
    colData.push(col.textContent.trim())}
 })
list_of_cells.push(colData);
} );
console.log(list_of_cells);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently doing some testing to determine how it works with the site that I'm scraping.   I might have to specific each td class, because using this -- td = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td") -- after your code is still creating issues.  I'm working on the latter now.

Comment: I'm still getting empty strings in my result sets.  I'm currently trying to be as precise as possible with my xpath finds.  For example, I have tried this, but it fails: 
 row.find_element_by_xpath("//td[starts-with(@class,'th-synopsis')]/span").text).  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want to get the text only if all the `td`s in a row have data, right?

Comment: Correct.  I'm new to selenium and need to review the documentation for this module in MUCH greater detail.

Comment: let me update the answer, that will get only rows which does not have any empty cells.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm running tests now. I had assumed that this was a simple issue, but it has turned into something more.   THANKS for all the assistance in troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: After running many tests, I still have to add a secondary check when processing the data collected.  The secondary check looks for an empty string in a list pulled from a nestled list.  I'm unsure why this line isn't catching empty row elements - rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='mytable']//tr[not(td[string-length(text())=0])]").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194782/discussion-between-supputuri-and-life-is-complex).

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex That xpath is explicitly for the rows that does not have empty columns. We can chat in discussion room if you have any more questions.

Comment: Without your assistance I would still be researching and testing.   Thanks again for all your assistance!!